# update mysql db when receive an email

Tags: php, mysql, email

i have some constraints about php.

can i update a record when i receive an email.
for example:
i have a table.

```
CREATE TABLE msg (
email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
msg varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
)TYPE=MyISAM;
```

i have a no-reply email. like. no-reply@example.com
so when no-reply@example.com receive an email from member. like: member@example.com and the body of the email like.

```
hii,. good morning world
```

so the script will run this query

```
$msg = '<the body of the email>'; //in this case 'hii,. good morning world'
$email = '<the email address of the sender>'; //in this case 'member@example.com'
$query = "UPDATE msg SET msg = '$msg' WHERE email = '$email'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

and my question is. how we know that no-reply@example.com receive an email and run the script.?

Comment: Why should anyone send an e-mail to an no-reply adress??

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this. If no-reply@example.com is a mailbox accessible via POP3 or IMAP you could have a script which logs in, checks for new messages, and triggers replies.

A simple solution would be to run this script every 10 minutes or so. If the script deletes messages after processing them, every time you see messages in the mailbox you know they are new. Otherwise your script will need to record the last message so it can only process newer messages on subsequent runs.

Check out PHP's mail extensions for some idea of how to talk to a POP3/IMAP mailbox. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: no-reply@example.com just an email with no control. so when no-reply@example.com receive an email. it just run the script.

Comment: If no-reply@example.com isn't a mailbox or isn't delivered to some sort of mail server then there is no way to know when someone replies. If you don't use a mailbox of some sort you will have to have access to the example.com mail server and configure it to run your script when it receives an email. That particular solution feels like overkill and is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Some email providers offer a push API which can remotely trigger your application when a certain email addresses receives an email. I think this still generally requires a mailbox though. http://mailgun.net/ does this.

Comment: no-reply.example.com is an email address where i made it from cpanel. but the email is no control from me.

Comment: @acoenblazt When you make an email address on cpanel, it has a mailbox. The Imap link show above will show you how to read the mail from the mailbox. But you need to run a cron job, which basically triggers your script in intervals and you script will check the mailbox for new messages and respond how you set it up.